# I am writing a program that generates a list of integer coordinates for all points in the first quadrant from (1, 1) to (5, 5)

Tags: python

And I have to use list comprehension which i dont how to use because i have just started learning python
It displays the error message

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

so this is the code i have currently written

```
    frst_quadrant = 1
    for a in frst_quadrant:
        a =+ 1
        if a > 5:
            break
        elif a < 5:
        a =+ 1
            print(a)
            continue
        else:
            a =+ 1
            print(a)
            continue
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: `frst_quadrant` is an integer because you are setting it to be equals 1 right before the execution of your for loop. It is not an iterable so it will never work.

Comment: `for a in 1:` doesn't make sense

Comment: So tell me what should I do

Comment: you're writing a `for` loop, but you're also incrementing `a` (or trying to) inside by writing lines such as `a =+ 1` (which, by the way seems wrong to me, shouldn't that be `a += 1`)?. To the point that it seems like what you are trying to write is a logic equivalent to some kind of `while` loop.

Comment: I think what you should do is revisit a tutorial or your course material, you've missed a few "fundamental" building blocks that you should revisit. Specifically, i'd encourage you to revisit `for` loops specifically, and loops in general.

Comment: Step away from the code and describe in words the steps you need to take to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line you have written first_quadrant as 1 which is an integer. In the second line you are trying to use a for loop over an integer. This is not allowed and therefore the error.

You could do it in many other ways. I am writing two such possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

```py
first_quadrant = 1
last_quadrant = 5
coordinates = []
for x in range(first_quadrant,last_quadrant +1, 1):
    for y in range(first_quadrant,last_quadrant +1, 1):
        coordinates.append([x,y])
print(coordinates)
```

**Solution 2**

```py
coordinates = [[x,y)] for x in range(1, 5+1,1) for y in range(1, 5+1, 1)]
print(coordinates)
```